# Как получить имя файла из File Input @angular/material

Tags: typescript, angular

Пробую использовать компонент @angular-material-components/file-input в проекте на Angular
смотрю примеры его использования:
[file-input](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-material-components/file-input)

```
<mat-form-field>
   <ngx-mat-file-input [formControl]="fileControl">
   </ngx-mat-file-input>
</mat-form-field>
```

ts:

```
export class DemoFileInputComponent implements OnInit {
fileControl: FormControl;
constructor() {
    this.fileControl= new FormControl(this.files);
  }
 ngOnInit() {
    this.fileControl.valueChanges.subscribe((files: any) => {
      if (!Array.isArray(files)) {
        this.files = [files];
      } else {
        this.files = files;
      }
      console.log('valueChanges');
    })
}
```

На форме все работает, выбираю файл, он появляется в поле ввода. Вот только я не пойму как мне получить его имя и полный путь в коде?
Еще браузер выдает ошибку:

```
Error: formControlName must be used with a parent formGroup directive.  You'll want to add a formGroup
       directive and pass it an existing FormGroup instance (you can create one in your class).
```

Хотя пример взят из документации.

Comment: если вы имете ввиду this.fileControl.valueChanges.subscribe((files: any) => {
то он не вызывается, я туда ставил console.log()

Comment: Как они туда попадают? Я не вижу вызова функции this.fileControl.valueChanges

Comment: так в том то и дело, что не срабатывает ни разу

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122963/discussion-between-indevx-and-alex-serg).